# Custom functions unavailable from BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript in an XBAP

Tags: c#, javascript, xbap

I'm attempting to use an XBAP to acquire TWAIN Images but I'm not even getting that far. I can't seem to get the BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript to allow me to talk back to the javascript on the host page.

- I am running the XBAP in an iframe.
- I tried full trust (even though that should be a requirement).
- I'm testing on IE9, .NET Framework 4.0
- The BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript is not null, I can use the normal window methods, like .Close().

My code looks like this:

### Index.html:

```
<p id="someP">My cat's breath smells like cat food.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function WorkDamnit() {
        $('#someP').hide();
    }
</script>

<iframe src="@Url.Content("~/XBAPs/WPFBrowserApplication1.xbap")" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500" />
```

### Page1.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript == null)
        throw new ApplicationException("hostscript is null");
    else
        BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript.WorkDamnit();
}
```

### I get:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method '[object Window].WorkDamnit' not found.
```

### New Info:

This scenario works properly from other PCs on the network and I found out why. IE9 has a setting turned on by default called "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View". This causes the page to render in "IE7 mode" and the javascript function is available from the XBAP. If I click Document Mode: (under the F12 developer tools console) and switch to IE9 mode then it no longer works (as above). On my own PC it uses IE9 mode by default (As it should) and it does not work unless I manually switch to IE7 mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 does not expose `BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript` unless it is in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 3):

In IE9, window methods are available to you, so you could try setTimeout

```
BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript.setTimeout("WorkDamnit()",0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its due to IE security settings.
IE by default blocks the scripts if page is opened from local drive.
IE should display the warning message as "'To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted...."

However you can change the settings 
Check the checkbox "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer"

[image: IE settings]

Comment: Checking this option didn't work, but it IS working on some other workstations here (Win7/IE9 and XP/IE8) so you might be on the right track. I just wish there was SOME indication on my PC as to why it isn't allowing this to work.

Comment: I don't think that option applies because scripts ARE (and have been) running. I just can't access the functions from the XBAP. I do get script warnings if I open hmtl files straight from file:// URI.

Comment: Another way to resolve this is to add Mark of the web (MOTW) in the html page see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks but I'm not experiencing this problem. The "allow active content" has no effect on my problem, only compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty far after the fact but I wanted to chime in because I've dealt with this problem and it's an ugly one.

As you have observed, the machines it runs on work because they are running in compatibility mode.   You can instruct IE9 to render your page using compatibility mode by adding the following tag to your html documents:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

I'm confident in saying, adding this tag is your only 'solution.'  I've spent weeks looking for a better one and this is the one I'm still stuck with.

For whatever reason the `ScriptInteropHelper` is rife with problems in IE9.  It hasn't gotten a lot of attention from Microsoft, likely because it's obscure functionality.  That said, particularly because IE7 and IE8 have all sorts of quirks, it's extraordinarily annoying you have to run in compatibility mode.  There are a number of MSDN articles, for example [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/935c8f1e-74a5-4eb7-b3e6-0824c59ccc0a) and [enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e386047c-00ae-4607-8046-9a54210773f2) that discuss the issue further.

Comment: In the end, I went with an ActiveX scanning control. It works and doesn't force me to use compatibility mode (also, I found one that has an activex AND npapi version So it can work in most browsers).

It seems that Silverlight is still supported but XBAPs are forgotten.

Comment: Hi Luggage, may I know what ActiveX control you chose?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still wondering about this problem, I got found out a solution. Basically from document object you can communicate properly without any hacks in latest browsers and with HTML5 doctype.

I wrote a blog post that contains the codes and examples:

[XBAP and Javascript with IE9 or newer - Solution for MissingMethodException problems](http://hotzblog.com/xbap-and-javascript-with-ie9-or-newer-solution-for-missingmethodexception-problems/)

Quickly explained this works properly:

Javascript

```
document.ResponseData = function (responseData) {
    alert(responseData);
}
```

C# XBAP

```
var hostScript = BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript;
hostScript.document.ResponseData("Hello World");
```

It can be then used to pass C# object to Javascript and used as "proxy" object. Check that blog post for details how that can be used.

Comment: Are you saying just use `BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript.document` instead of just `BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript`?

Comment: Not exactly. Extending functions to document object can be called from C# through BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript.document.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript.setTimeout("WorkDamnit()",0);

its working but if i want to send callback functions to js how can i send object with setTimeout ?

---

when using for ie8 
its working good

```
dynamic host = BrowserInteropHelper.HostScript;
host.sampleJSFunction(new CallbackObject(this));
```